# OpenSceneGraph Emissive Lighting

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

I have a rather large mesh, (which I load with osgDB). It also has several sub-meshes.

I am trying to set the emission lighting. However I can see (suspect) that only the 1st sub-mesh is lit up. How is it possible to light up all the sub-meshes.
I am not using lighting to lit up the scene.

What is the recommended approach?

```
int main()
{
    osg::Node * cytBuilding = osgDB::readNodeFile( OBJ_FILE );


    osg::Group * root = new osg::Group();
    osg::PositionAttitudeTransform * scenePAT = new osg::PositionAttitudeTransform();
    root->addChild(scenePAT);
    scenePAT->addChild( cytBuilding );




    //material
    osg::Material* material = new osg::Material();
    material->setAmbient(osg::Material::FRONT, osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
    material->setDiffuse(osg::Material::FRONT, osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
    material->setSpecular(osg::Material::FRONT, osg::Vec4(0.0,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
    material->setEmission(osg::Material::FRONT, osg::Vec4(1.0,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
    osg::StateSet* stateset = new osg::StateSet();
    stateset->setAttributeAndModes(material,osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE|osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    root->setStateSet(stateset);


    // viewer
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;

    viewer.setSceneData( root );
    viewer.realize();
    return viewer.run();
```

As I read the mesh (osgDB::readNodeFile()), it display following error messages

```
*** line not handled *** :map_bump
*** line not handled *** :bump
*** line not handled *** :map_opacity
*** line not handled *** :map_d
*** line not handled *** :refl
*** line not handled *** :map_kS
*** line not handled *** :map_Ns
```

Resulting display was:
[image]

Same mesh when I display with meshlab, I see
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on how the StateSets within the model are organized.
Could you try to enforce lighting on your root node?

```
stateset->setMode( GL_LIGHTING, osg::StateAttribute::OVERRIDE | osg::StateAttribute::ON );
```

You could also try to implement a small visitor to dump all Materials and StateSets within the model to see how they are assigned, maybe its overridden per node with a `OVERRIDE|PROTECTED` flag.
Just for testing, did you try to apply your Material to all Geodes or Geometries within the model?

Comment: I set a material to a setState and set it to the root node, will this not apply the material to all the node underneath the root?

Comment: Not unless they are  `OVERRIDE | PROTECTED` on lower levels. Are you sure, the model's normal are correct? Did you try to apply normal smoothing visitor, just for testing: `static void osgUtil::SmoothingVisitor::smooth(osg::Geometry& g)`?